# When finding the basis of a subspace and having a free variable, would the dimension be just one?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> So I am not sure if this is the correct way and answer to this problem but here is my solution

> The problem:
> \begin{equation*}
> {\bigg( x,y,z \bigg)| x+y=0 \space and \space x-2z=0}
> \end{equation*}
> Solution:
> $$ 
> x  \ -2z=0\\
>     x+y   =0\\x=2z\\y=-2z\\So,\\ \bigg(x,y,z\bigg)=\bigg(2,-2,1)z\\ basis :\\<(2,-2,1)>\\dimension \space is \space 1
> $$

> So is my solution correct and would it be a dimension of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed your work is correct. Another way of looking at it would be geometrically. The set of points in question you're looking at is $$ \{(x,y,z): x+y=0 \text{ and } x-2z=0\}$$ can be thought of as the intersection of two planes. In this case since the planes are not parallel, the intersection is an object of dimension 1, a line, whose direction vector you've found in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is Correct!

In terms of matrix language, we have to solve $$AX=0$$ where $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &1&0\\1&0&-2 \end{pmatrix}$ , $X=(x,y,z)^T$. So Treat $A$ as a linear map form $\Bbb R^3$ to $\Bbb R^2$. Since rank of $A$ is 2, by dimension theorem, null space of $A$ has dimension 1.